# moving elements in css

Tags: css, wordpress

the home page of my website is displaying differently for a 1920px screen (big desktop screen) than for a 1366px (15" laptop) screen.

On the larger screen it is perfect, but on the smaller screen, there is a big space between the menu, text below and then the banner image.

I am trying to fix this by wrapping the 1366px screen in a media query (although it's weird I should have to do this.. it's the only thing on the whole site that has shown up differently)

The problem is, in the media query, I have moved the text up, but I just CANNOT get the banner image to move up, without all the text moving down again. I have tried to do negative padding and negative top margins but it doesn't work. Can someone please help me move the banner image up.. or better yet, explain why it's performing differently on this screen resolution.  The website is www.flowersforeveryone.co.za.. although obviously depending on your resolution you may or may not see the issue. I have attached an image.

The CSS is -

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1400px) {

.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .container{
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.page-banner-wrap .page-banner .page-header > .page-title{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
    margin-top: -100px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 590px;
    font-size: 21pt;
    line-height: 1.2;
    word-wrap:break-word; max-width:38ch;
}

.page-banner-wrap .page-banner .banner-content{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#lsx-banner .tagline {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}
```

[image: home page]

Answer (score 0):

There are some other big mistakes you should fix first :D But nvm.

Change inside of

```
<div class="page-banner-image" style="background-position: center center; background-image:url(https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Home-3-1.png);"></div>
```

the background position to

```
background-position: top center;
```

But some other sutff might happen if you keep using those CSS, i recommend using

`background-size: contain`

instead of what you did there. So it could look like

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: top center;
background-size: contain;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Home-3-1.png);
```

Comment: what do you mean big mistakes???  where do i change the div class? it's a wordpress site obviously, so not sure where i would find this.. (also I don't want to change the main details for this because it's working on all other resolutions)... do you know why this change is only occurring on this sized screen resolution? Thanks!